# How can I define logstash configuration file for redis

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash

I was working on Logstash and using Redis as input. I'm new to Redis. 
Earlier, I implemented the configuration file with JDBC on MySQL.
Following is the code:

```
jdbc {jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => ""
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => " com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    clean_run => true
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "time"
    tracking_column_type =>"timestamp"
    statement => "SELECT time, firstname, lastname, email FROM sample.sample where time > :sql_last_value;"
    schedule => " * * * * * *"
}
```

I want to implment same with the redis, after research, I found this:

```
redis {
host => "127.0.0.1"
port => "6379"
type => "redis-input"
data_type => "list"
key => "0"
message_format => "json_event"
}
```

I'm using predis to insert data into redis using

```
$redisRes = $client->hmget(insert_id, array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email'));
```

where insert_id is unique for every insertion.
Now, my question is:
1. As insert_id is unique in my case, how can I define this in config file.
2. data_type can be string, one of ["list", "channel", "pattern_channel"], but I'm using hash.
3. how can I give condition (like in jdbc, we have statement and sql_last_value, do we have such in redis input)
I just want redis input to work like jdbc input

Answer (score 1):

The Redis input works differently than SQL: you are de-queuing events from either a list by popping available items, or by subscribing to a channel.

Redis can't be used, as you wouldn't know the keys to query in advance. If you still need unique keys for the data, add them to your data when pushing into Redis.

Comment: Can you pls provide me some sample/example code for the same.

Comment: The input would look similarly to:

`input {
  redis {
    data_type => ""list""
    key => ""myListName""
    host => ""127.0.0.1""
  }
}`.

To see how this would work, you could use another Logstash pipeline that adds messages to Redis for the first script to de-queue them (this will read a message from the keyboard, add a unique id to it and enqueue to the list that Redis listens to):

`input {
  stdin {}
}

filter {
  uuid {
    target => ""uuid""
  }
}

output {
  redis {
    data_type => ""list""
    key => ""myListName""
    host => ""127.0.0.1""
  }
}`.